# Mexopencv mex file not found

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex, matlab-compiler

I have called a mex file compiled using mexopencv from matlab. The program runs in matlab and gives no problem but when I convert the matlab to a c++ shared library using the matlab deploytool and compile to an exe application while running the exe I get an error that the mexfile is not found or it is not a valid filepath or directory. What could be the reason behind this??Should I add any additional libraries or path in my Makefile or should I change the system path?? I am using linux and MATLAB R2012a,mexopencv.

Note that the mex file can be called from matlab and it gives an output but it can't be called by the exe. I am trying to run the facedetection module which is already in the mexopencv samples.It requires an xml file as an input. Why isn't it able to detect the mex file and the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The deploytool should bring in MEX files, so I would have to guess that the dependencies of mexopencv files are not being included in the generated library or accessible via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD`.  These would be the OpenCV libraries (e.g. libopencv_core.so.2.4, libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4, etc.).

Check for additional dependencies of the mexopencv mex files with `ldd` (for Windows folks, use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)).  **EDIT**: Then add them!